# How do I interpret this date on tortillas?

Tags: storage-lifetime

This is printed on the package of corn tortillas DA JUN 17 19 L3 15:18.  What does this mean?

Comment: Might just be a manufacture date: *Date June 17 2019 Line 3 at 3:18pm.* If something goes wrong, that will tell the manufacturer which machine is messing up (L3-> Line 3).

Answer (score 1):

You could guess it's Best Before June 17th 2019, but the only way to confirm it would be check a new pack at the supermarket & see if it's a couple of months ahead of that, with a similar pattern, e.g. Oct 05 19 etc would confirm it.

Either that or it's the manufacture date.

Depending on when you bought them would hint as to which it might be.